# expected 'while' or expected '}'

Tags: c++, function, menu, user-defined-functions

I'm having a problem with my function `int getUserOption()`. There is an error on the upper curly brace of the function (right under the function header) that says `expected a ';'` and one error on the lower curly brace that says `expected a 'while'`. I can't seem to find anyone with similar problems and I know that functions don't have a semicolon following them if you're defining them. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix/avoid it with my next functions?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int getUserOption();

int main()
{
int option;
cout << "hello world\n";
    do {
        option = getUserOption();
        switch(option) {
        case 0:
            break;
        case 1:
            cout << "You chose COPY\n";
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "You chose FACTORIAL\n";
            break;
        case 3:
            cout << "You chose COUNT\n";
            break;
        case 4:
            cout << "You chose COUNT BYTES\n";
            break;

return 0;
    }

    int getUserOption()
    {
string userSelection;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
cout << "Enter an option as it appears before the colon: \n";
cout << "  QUIT: Exit the program\n";
cout << "  1: Copy the contents of a file\n";
cout << "  2: Calculate the factorial of an integer (between 1 and 12)\n";
cout << "  3: Count the words in a file\n";
cout << "  4: Count the bytes in a file\n";

getline(cin,userSelection);

    if(userSelection[0] == '1') {
        return 1;
    } else if (userSelection[0] == '2') {
        return 2;
    } else if (userSelection[0] == '3') {
        return 3;
    } else if (userSelection[0] == '4') {
        return 4;
    } else if (userSelection == "QUIT") {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The compiler is telling you exactly what is wrong.  You have a `do` and no `while`.

Answer (score 3):

you need to close out your `do...while` loop and your `switch` statement.

```
do {
    ...
    switch(option) {
        ...
    } // end of switch statement
}while(...); // end of do-while loop

return 0;
```